# Speech recognition not working for android app using SpeechRecognizer as a service

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, service, speech-recognition

Just to preface, I am completely new to Android Studio and am a Java beginner in general, but Im trying to work on making an android 'siri' like app where I could say a phrase and the phone would automatically pick up the phrase and input into the app whatever I said.

To do this, I opted to run speech recognizer as a background service.

To activate the service in MainActivity

```
  disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View disable) {
                Intent start_action = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundProcess.class);
                startService(start_action);
            }
```

Code for background process

```
package com.ia;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;


import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class BackgroundProcess extends Service implements RecognitionListener{

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 1000;
    private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
    private int speak() {
        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(getApplicationContext());
        speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);

        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass()
                .getPackage().getName());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 10);

        speechRecognizer.startListening(intent);

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        speak();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        ArrayList resultList = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        for (int i=0;i < resultList.size();i++){
            Log.d("speech", "result = " + resultList.get(i).toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hello.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }
}
```